# Photo capture in portrait mode but photo automatic convert in landscape I want to photo in portrait mode Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, image-capture

in my Android app I capture the photo in portrait mode but when photo is saved is convert in landscape mode but I want to save photo in portrait mode

> CaptureActivity.java

```
public class CaptureActivity extends Activity 
{   
     // Activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    // imageview for display captured image
    ImageView imagecapture;

    // file url to store image/video
    public Uri fileUri; 

    // Classes For Database
    private     SQLiteDatabase  mSQLiteDatabase = null;
    private     DB_Helper       mDB_Helper = null;

    public static ContextWrapper contextWrapper;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.capturephoto);  

        imagecapture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagecapture);
        contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());

       // Checking camera availability
        if(!isDeviceSupportCamera()) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            captureImage();
        }

    }

     /* Opening DB */
    private void Open_Database() 
    {
        mDB_Helper = new DB_Helper(this);
        mSQLiteDatabase = mDB_Helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /* Closing DB */
    private void Close_Database() 
    {
        if (mSQLiteDatabase != null && mDB_Helper != null) {
            mSQLiteDatabase.close();
            mDB_Helper.close();
        }
    }

     /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() 
    {
        if(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) 
        {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
     */
    private void captureImage()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fileUri);
          // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }

    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * 
     * */

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) 
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
            {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } 
            else 
            {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }    



    /**
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() 
    {
        try 
        {         

            // for open database
            Open_Database();

            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = getImage(fileUri.getPath(),getApplicationContext() );
                 imagecapture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date myDate = new Date();
            String realdatetime = dateformat.format(myDate);
            Log.e("Current Date","------>"+realdatetime);

            mDB_Helper.Insert_MYPHOTOS_Table(mSQLiteDatabase,"title",realdatetime, "description",fileUri.getPath());

            // for close database
            Close_Database();

        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public Bitmap getImage(String path,Context con) throws IOException
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        int srcWidth = options.outWidth;
        int srcHeight = options.outHeight;
        int[] newWH =  new int[2];
        newWH[0] = srcWidth/2;
        newWH[1] = (newWH[0]*srcHeight)/srcWidth;

        int inSampleSize = 1;
        while(srcWidth / 2 >= newWH[0]){
            srcWidth /= 2;
            srcHeight /= 2;
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }

         options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap sampledSrcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
        String s=exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
        System.out.println("Orientation>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+s);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        float rotation = rotationForImage(con, Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
        if (rotation != 0f) {
            matrix.preRotate(rotation);
        }

        Bitmap pqr=Bitmap.createBitmap(
                sampledSrcBitmap, 0, 0, sampledSrcBitmap.getWidth(), sampledSrcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);


        return pqr;
    }   


    public  float rotationForImage(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            String[] projection = { Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                return c.getInt(0);
            }
        } else if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
            try {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
                int rotation = (int)exifOrientationToDegrees(
                        exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL));
                return rotation;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }

        }
        return 0f;
    }

    private static float exifOrientationToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
        if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            return 90;
        } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
            return 180;
        } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            return 270;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
     * */

    /**
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) 
    {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) 
    {

           File mediaFile = null;

           Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
           if(isSDPresent)
           {
               File directory= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Mymemoryphotos");

                if(!directory.exists())
                {   
                    Log.e("Create External Directory","------>");
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }

                 // Create a media file name
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());


                if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) 
                {
                    mediaFile = new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".JPEG");
                }
                else 
                {

                    return null;

                }
           }
           else
           {

               File directory = contextWrapper.getDir("Mymemoryphotos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                if(!directory.exists())
                {   
                    Log.e("Create Internal Directory","------>");
                    directory.mkdirs();

                }

                // Create a media file name
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());              

                if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) 
                {
                    mediaFile = new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".JPEG");
                }
                else 
                {

                    return null;

                }
           }

        return mediaFile;
    }

}
```

> I want result like this when photo saved in sdcard

[image]

> My current result when capture image in portrait mode but photo auto
>   convert to landscape mode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExifInterface` to read photo EXIF tags & rotate bitmap when you show it. You may check [this](http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.com/2013/06/get-images-from-camera-using.html) for some sample code, however it needs to be edited & cleaned a bit

Comment: hey when i show image in imageview is already done with potrait  but i want to rotate image when i was saved in sdcard it is possible

Comment: I don't uderstand you. Please try to construct sentences better

Comment: see first i capture the image in portrait mode than i saved that image in sdcard but this image is saved in landscape mode not in portrait mode image is automatically rotate in landscape mode

Comment: Well, I don't yet understand you. Also, READ my answer at last.